# Use of Lambda Expression firstordefault()

Tags: c#, user-interface, lambda

```
public Users SelectById(long iId)
{
   return UOWUser.UsersRepository.Entities.Where(x => x.Id == iId).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

What is the Use of `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence contains no elements... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It will return the first instance found. If there are no results it will return a default value for the type in question.

Usually the default is Null or zero. Usage of this extension is used to **not** throw an exception such as when `First()` is used. Use `First()` when one knows that there will always be data and use `FirstOrDefault()` when the query may not return any data.